# How can I visualize Groceries data set in a tabular format?

Tags: r, dataset, sparse-matrix, tabular-form

As far as I understood, `Groceries` in `arules` package is in sparse matrix form.

Suppose, I want to see that in a normal tabular form.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

This should give you a standard matrix `Groceries@data`. I believe Groceries is a special class, not a standard sparse matrix. Try `class(Groceries)`.